# How to search a numeric range in a string

Tags: php, mysql

I got a MySQL table with a column containing values like `100 - 200 °C` or `135 °C`.
I want to search for rows between a numeric range e.g. `>100` or `> 120, < 140`.
How to solve this with the existing table structure?
If there is no good solution, how to change the table structure? Two columns with e.g. lowestTemperature, highestTemperature?

Thank you very much.

Comment: Change the data structure to two columns, with the lowest temperature and the highest temperature.  Then the query will be easy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If changing the table structure is possible, then having a lowest and highest temperature would be really easy to query.

For example, if you wanted to make sure it was in a range >100, you could say something like:

```
SELECT stuff
FROM myTable
WHERE lowTemperature > 100;
```

Or to check that it falls within a specific range, you can use the `AND` operator on both columns like this:

```
SELECT stuff
FROM myTable
WHERE lowTemperature > 120 AND highTemperature < 140
```

Answer (score 0):

It's better to refactor your table by making two columns with `lowestTemperature` and `highestTemperature` like you said, so in the future it will be easy to fetch data even better for performance...

I suggest to add your two columns and fetch your table with PHP using `preg_match()` (see php documentation) function to parse the  lowestTemperature and the highestTemperature then add them to your new columns, finally delete this "dirty" column.

Comment: An up would be great :)